# Async pipe with Search custom pipe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pipe, angular8

I have a dataSource which is an observable because I recibe data from my API.
I want to search by text that data and filter it:

Here i have my Pipe.ts:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterText'
})
export class FilterTextPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(values, searchTerm): any {

      if (!values || !searchTerm) {
          return _.get(values, '_value', '');
      }

      return values._value.filter( item =>
         item.provider_business_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      );

  }

}
```

And here i have my template:

```
<mat-card class="card-provider m-2 p-2" *ngFor="let provider of obs | filterText:searchText | async" />
```

Also here is my component.ts:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
    dataSource;
    searchText;
    obs: Observable<any>;

    constructor(
        private _providersService: ProvidersService,
        private dialog: MatDialog,
        private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        this.getProviders();
    }

    getProviders() {
        this._providersService.getAllProviders().subscribe(
            data => {
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                this.obs = this.dataSource.connect();
            }
        );
    }
```

I have done it this way because i need to paginate my card elements but i can't combine both, my paginator and my FilterPipe.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm i found a solution, i don't know if its the most "clean" way but it works!

I removed the property call of my observer in my Pipe:

pipe.ts:

```
 @Pipe({
      name: 'filterText'
    })
    export class FilterTextPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(values, searchTerm): any {

          if (!searchTerm) {
              return values;
          }

          return values.filter( item =>
             item.provider_business_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1
          );

      }

    }
```

And my template looks like this:

```
<mat-card class="card-provider m-2 p-2" *ngFor="let provider of obs | async | filterText:searchText" >
```

Comment: Note that pipes are generally not recommended for filtering operations because they are run very often - consult angular docs for more information